# ‘Mat’ was not declared in this scope opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, libtiff

I followed this guide to install openCV on Ubuntu:
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

When I try to execute the following program:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>
#include <tiffio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  string imageName("images/400nm.tif");
  TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen(imageName.c_str(), "r");
  Mat image;


  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error executing the command "g++ ssim.cpp -o ssim -ltiff":

> ssim.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: ssim.cpp:19:3: error: ‘Mat’ was
>   not declared in this scope    Mat image;    ^~~ ssim.cpp:19:3: note:
>   suggested alternative: In file included from
>   /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:59:0,
>                    from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48,
>                    from ssim.cpp:2: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:771:18: note:   ‘cv::Mat’ 
>   class CV_EXPORTS Mat

Does somebody know why I get this and how to solve it? 
I'm new at using opencv and libtiff so I have no idea about what to do to solve...

Comment: I don't understand what should I do... I tried to add "using namespace cv" or to use "cv::Mat" but nothing happen.

Comment: Can you post the full error message when using `cv::Mat`?

Comment: Try to compile `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
int main(){
  cv::Mat image;
  return 0;
}` Do you get the same error?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really necessary to build openCV from source. Try installing it with

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

and try to compile it again.

Also like you said in your comment, make sure you either use namespace cv or cv::Mat.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command:

> g++ ssim.cpp -o ssim -ltiff -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs

I don't get compiler errors but when I try to execute the command ./ssim I get:

> ./ssim: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.3.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Using the command `ldd name_of_your_executable` (e.g. ldd ssim) you will get a list of all the library it depend on and the expected path the compiler taught the library was as well as an indication of the missing libraries.
It will help you to identify the library path to add using the compiler option -L 
(e.g. if the compiler expect to find `libopencv_core.so.3.4` in `/lib/opencv` so you compilation command should be: `g++ ssim.cpp -o ssim -ltiff -L/lib/opencv/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs` )